# Compare the integrals $I_1= \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{\sin(\sin(x))}{\sin(x)} \text{dx} $

Tags: integration

Compare the integrals $I_1= \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{\sin(\sin(x))}{\sin(x)} \text{dx} , I_2= \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{\sin x}{x} \text{dx}, I_3= \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{ \sin (\tan (x))}{\tan (x)} \text{dx}$

We know the following inequalities,over $[0, \frac{\pi}{2}]$

$x > \sin x$ and as $\sin x$ is increasing, $\sin x > \sin(\sin x)$ But again $x . \sin x$ , so, I cannot judge between $I_1, I_2$ about which one is greater.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For $x\in(0,\frac{\pi}{2})$, $\tan x>x>\sin x$.

Let $\displaystyle f(x)=\frac{\sin x}{x}$. Then $\displaystyle f'(x)=\frac{x\cos x-\sin x}{x^2}=\frac{\cos x(x-\tan x)}{x^2}<0$

So $f$ is strictly decreasing on $[0,\frac{\pi}{2}]$.

If $x\in(0,\frac{\pi}{2})$, $0<\sin x<x<\frac{\pi}{2}$. So we have $f(x)<f(\sin x)$.

$$I_1=\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}f(\sin x)dx>\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2}f(x)dx=I_2$$

Note that for $x>\frac{\pi}{2}$, $|f(x)|\le\frac{1}{x}<f(\frac{\pi}{2})$

If $x\in(0,\tan^{-1}\frac{\pi}{2})$, $0<x<\tan x<\frac{\pi}{2}$. So we have $f(x)>f(\tan x)$.

If $x\in(\tan^{-1}\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2})$, $\tan x>\frac{\pi}{2}$ and hence  $f(\tan x)<|f(\tan x)|<f(\frac{\pi}{2})<f(x)$.

$$I_2=\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}f(x)dx>\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2}f(\tan x)dx=I_3$$